# What to do if you don't have 2,000 rep to rollback an edit?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068250/question-on-uniformly-distributed-random-variable/), I converted the question so that it was strictly what the OP asked written in LaTeX notation and deleted an incorrect tag. However, the person who edited it after I did changed some E values to $\mathbb{E}$ and remove some dollar signs (which was unnecessary, as not everyone uses $\mathbb{E}$, and just removing $ signs for numbers is a very trivial edit), and added *back* the incorrect tag.

I don't have the reputation to rollback this edit.

What do I do in this case?

Comment: This makes it sound like the other editor saw your edits and decided to undo them. Is it possible instead that these were concurrent edits (both working from the same original text) and that the other editor simply submitted their changes after yours, thereby overwriting them? I notice that the other editor subsequently removed the tag you had removed, which they might well do if they saw your edits only after submitting theirs.

Comment: @DavidK I think that if you are editing a post and someone submit an edit before you, then you can't submit your edit.

Comment: @Surb That does seem to be the intended interface, [like this example](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11231/edit-couldnt-be-submitted-how-to-finish-review-load-title-and-tag-edits-asy), but whether it works 100% of the time is another question. The two edits in question each had to be approved by two reviewers, unlike the "can't submit" case I linked to (which was an edit _by_ a reviewer), so there's another possible complication. I don't know how we determine for sure what happened (except maybe if we hear from the other editor or the reviewers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you think that the edit deviates from  OP's intent, you can point this out to them in a comment. Users can rollback edits on their own posts, regardless of reputation.

Another option is to "rollback via copy-paste" (i.e., submit an edit that is identical to your prior edit), but I consider this excessive in cases of minor disagreement over formatting. Edit wars are bad enough without them cluttering the revision history and the review queue for suggested edits.

Comment: I have not been able to find the option to rollback edits. Can you guide me on this? I had no luck clicking "edit" and searching for the rollback feature.

Comment: The rollback option is available only on posts which you can edit directly. Until 2000 rep, that means: your own posts, and community wiki posts. See the first paragraph of my answer.